# use of undefined type in circular dependency

Tags: c++, class, oop, visual-c++, circular-dependency

I have folllowing code that have circular dependency i search on **stack overflow & GPT** i find this solution.

> By forward declaring the Tps class, the DocumentMetaData class can now use a pointer to the Tps class without needing its full definition.

**I tried this** but Visual studio still giving me error `use of undefined type TPS` in `DocumentMetaData`.

```
class Tps;

class DocumentMetaData {
     Tps* tps;
};

class Document { 
   DocumentMetaData data;
};

class Tps {
   Document doc;
   DocumentMetaData data;
};
```

**Any idea** how can i fix this issue?

How declare classes as it is in example code.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDD9z.png)

Comment: Can't reproduce. Your code compiles in MSVC (as well as in GCC, clang, and any other standard-conforming compiler)

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/ please can you try this here?

Comment: full source code is here https://github.com/Zain-ul-din/Algo-and-Data-Structures-Road-Map/blob/master/TPS.h

Comment: You need to move the definitions of the `DocumentMetaData` member functions to be after where TPS is defined in order for those definitions to know about `TPS`

Comment: The error message is about a type named `TPS`. The code has a forward declaratory a type named `Tps`. They’re not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're showing won't happen with the code you posted.

The error occurs when you try to do this:

```cpp
class Tps;

class DocumentMetaData {
     Tps* tps = new Tps;
};
```

This can be dealt with by rearranging the code a bit, so the code to initialize `tps` is *after* the full definition of `Tps`.

```cpp
class Tps;

class DocumentMetaData {
     Tps* tps;
     // declare, but don't yet define a ctor for initialization
     DocumentMetaData();
};

class Document { 
   DocumentMetaData data;
};

// Fully define Tps:
class Tps {
   Document doc;
   DocumentMetaData data;
};

// Now Tps is defined, so we can implement the ctor:
inline DocumentMetaData::DocumentMetaData() : tps(new Tps) { }
```

And as a side note, C++ is case sensitive, so (for example) `TPS` and `Tps` aren't the same.